# Cache Zend Framework homepage on nginx

Tags: caching, nginx, zend-framework, html

I have zend framework 1.12 based site working with nginx

I installed wnmp on windows 7 professional to test Windows, nginx, mariadb, php7

I want to cache home page which is localhost or localhost/
which internally calls index.php using index.php

similarly urls http://localhost/conference/sessions/date/2015-04/12/page/1 conference - controller sessions - action request params date, and page with respective values

I want to cache home page but I have looked but nothing specific is available

Here is my nginx.conf that works without caching

here is what I have in my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    # Max value 16384
    worker_connections  8192;
    # Accept multiple connections
    multi_accept on;
}

# Settings that affect all server blocks
http {
    include php_processes.conf;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    access_log  logs/access.log;
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    sendfile on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 SSLv3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!DSS; 
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    gzip  on;
    # http server

# Begin HTTP Server
server {
    listen 80; # IPv4
    server_name localhost;

    ## Parametrization using hostname of access and log filenames.
    access_log logs/localhost_access.log;
    error_log logs/localhost_error.log;

    ## Root and index files.
    root html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    ## If no favicon exists return a 204 (no content error).
    location = /favicon.ico {
        try_files $uri =204;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    ## Don't log robots.txt requests.
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    ## Try the requested URI as files before handling it to PHP.
    location / {
        ## Regular PHP processing.
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files  $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   php_processes;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
        ## Static files
        location ~* \.(?:css|gif|htc|ico|js|jpe?g|png|swf)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay off;
            ## Set the OS file cache.
            open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=120s;
            open_file_cache_valid 45s;
            open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
            open_file_cache_errors off;
        }
        ## Keep a tab on the 'big' static files.
        location ~* ^.+\.(?:ogg|pdf|pptx?)$ {
            expires 30d;
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay off;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ @missing;
    } # / location
    location @missing {
        rewrite (.*) /index.php;
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Still searching the web looking for help;

Comment: Using ZendFramework 1.18 `# Begin HTTP Server
fastcgi_cache_path /home/k47/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYHOMEPAGE:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$cookie_abgap$cookie_PHPSESSID$cookie__ga$cookie__gat";
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 302 1m;
    location / {
  set $no_cache 0;
  fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
  fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;   
  fastcgi_cache MYHOMEPAGE;
  fastcgi_cache_valid 200 5m;
  add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
  ` Still getting "MISS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added Under http
note - add two underscores (__) if you cookie starts with and underscore (_)

```
fastcgi_cache_path /home/k47/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYHOMEPAGE:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_method$query_string$request_uri$cookie_one$cookie_two$cookie__ga$cookie__gat";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 302 1m;
```

Under server set a flag/variable which can be used to determine if we need caching or not
I have used other urls to cache and not cache with similar regex

```
set $no_cache 1;
if ($request_uri ~* "^/$")
{
    set $no_cache 0;
}
```

then finally under location {} I start with

```
fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;         
fastcgi_cache MYHOMEPAGE;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1m;
add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
add_header cache-control 'public, max-age=500';
```